# Rendering HTML from database in vuejs component in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to fetch data from my database and display it as HTML content but it only turns out as a string, I'm using vuejs component in laravel. This is the code

```
<div id="main-window" v-for="post in posts">
<div class="post">
  <div class="content">
    {{post.content}}
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I use the post.content as HTML?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use v-html binding. [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)

```
<div id="main-window" v-for="post in posts">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="content" v-html="post.content">
  </div>
</div>
```